# how should i make a button a link without losing the appearances?

Tags: html, django, web, frontend

I have been given a series of button elements which i have to change them into links
But they lose their appearances when i put them inside a  element.
how should i turn these buttons into links?

an example is the below button

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post-detail' post.slug %}" class="text-decoration-none">
  <button>
     read more
  </button>
</a>
```

the main purpose of these buttons is to navigate in pages and i can not replace them entirly with links

my buttons without links :
[image]

my buttons with links :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make only some of the buttons to be treated as links is to create `classes` for such buttons.

For instance, you may create a class called `links` for some the specific button of your choice and make this class have the attribute of links so it resemble as links than button for the chosen buttons you wish.

Example as below.

HTML code:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:post-detail' post.slug %}" class="text-decoration-none">
  <button class="links">
     read more
  </button>
</a>
```

CSS Code:

```
.links{
  background: none;
  border:none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.links:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

Demo - [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/23gex74s/)

This way you would be able to make certain buttons to behave link links.

Comment: i think you did not understand what i meant my dear.i have a button that have to act as link but with the appearances of a button like the photos i have provided now.

Comment: I get that @Hamedio. For this, as I mentioned above, you need to use CSS Classes to create the button style you wish as per your screenshot. In the class, you need to apply the attributes that you wish and add this class to the button where you want this style. It would then display the way you want.